# Inner Product and Scalar Question in Axler:

Tags: linear-algebra

This is question $\,26\,$ , chapter $\,6\,$  page $\,125\,$ ,  in Axler's Linear Algebra Done Right:

**Question:** Fix a vector $v\in V$ and define $T\in L(V,F)$ by $Tu = \langle u,v\rangle$. For $a \in F$, find a formula for $T^∗a$.

If $T\in L(V,F)$ then $T^*\in L(F, V)$ Fixing $a \in F$ then $T^*$ is unique vector in $V$ such that $\langle Tu, a\rangle = \langle u, T^*a\rangle$.

This seems wierd because inner product as defined only takes vectors as arguments and now it is taking scalars that is $\langle Tu, a\rangle$ or can the field $F$ in this case count as a vector space?

Comment: The field $F$ is indeed a $1$-dimensional vector space.

Comment: This is in fact an important example, because elements of $L(V,F)$ are "linear functionals" (which I'm sure you'll spend lots of time with).

Comment: Ok I see, from some searching "Every field is in fact a vector space over itself or over any of its subfields."

Comment: I changed $< Tu, a>$ and the like to $\langle Tu, a\rangle$.  That is standard usage.